Unable to migrate table using GORM
I created a Postgres database in superbase.com and wanted to connect it to my Golang project using GORM. But when I try to migrate the table, it throws an error.
#database.go

    package initializers
    
    import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os"
    
        "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
        "gorm.io/gorm"
    )
    
    var DB *gorm.DB
    
    func ConnectToDB() {
        var err error
    
        dsn := os.Getenv("DB_URL")
    
        DB, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(DB, "Failed to connect to database")
        } else {
    
            fmt.Println(DB, "Database connection established successfully")
        }
    
    }


#migrate.go

    package main
    
    import (
        "GinGorm/initializers"
        "GinGorm/models"
    )
    
    func init() {
        initializers.LoadEnvVariables()
        initializers.ConnectToDB()
    }
    
    func main() {
        post := &models.Post{}
        initializers.DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(post)
    
    }


Error thrown on command: go run migrate/migrate.go

&{0xc0001ce480  0 0xc00005f6c0 1} Database connection established
successfully panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil
pointer dereference [signal 0xc0000005 code=0x0 addr=0x28 pc=0xc19372]
goroutine 1 [running]: gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).getInstance(0x70?)
C:/Users/harsh/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.12/gorm.go:406 +0x12 gorm.io/gorm.(*DB).Debug(0x0)
C:/Users/harsh/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.25.12/gorm.go:329 +0x18 main.main()
D:/Code/Go/gin/GinGorm/migrate/migrate.go:15 +0x2e exit status 2


Assuming line 15 of migrate.go is initializers.DB.Debug().AutoMigrate(post), check that post is not nil.

The failure is in the Debug call. initializers.DB is invalid. It was never initialized.
The problem is here...
    DB, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

DB, err := declares local DB and err variables. This local DB is masking your global var DB *gorm.DB.
Instead, declare just the err and use =
    var err error
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

Here's a demonstration of the difference.
